# Correct usage of scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am a little confused by the [documentation for scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html).

Say for instance I have a function f: R^3 => R which is sampled on the vertices of the unit cube. I would like to interpolate so as to find values inside the cube.

```
import numpy as np

# Grid points / sample locations
X = np.array([[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [0,1,1], [1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,0], [1,1,1.]])

# Function values at the grid points
F = np.random.rand(8)
```

Now, `RegularGridInterpolator` takes a `points` argument, and a `values` argument.

> **points** : tuple of ndarray of float, with shapes (m1, ), ..., (mn, )
>   The points defining the regular grid in n dimensions.
>
> **values** : array_like, shape (m1, ..., mn, ...)
>   The data on the regular grid in n dimensions.

I interpret this as being able to call as such:

```
import scipy.interpolate as irp

rgi = irp.RegularGridInterpolator(X, F)
```

However, when I do so, I get the following error:

> ValueError: There are 8 point arrays, but values has 1 dimensions

What am I misinterpreting in the docs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok I feel silly when I answer my own question, but I found my mistake with help from the documentation of the original `regulargrid` lib:

https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/regulargrid

`points` should be a list of arrays that specifies how the points are spaced along each axis.

For example, to take the unit cube as above, I should set:

```
pts = ( np.array([0,1.]), )*3
```

or if I had data which was sampled at higher resolution along the last axis, I might set:

```
pts = ( np.array([0,1.]), np.array([0,1.]), np.array([0,0.5,1.]) )
```

Finally, `values` has to be of shape corresponding to the grid laid out implicitly by `points`. For example,

```
val_size = map(lambda q: q.shape[0], pts)
vals = np.zeros( val_size )

# make an arbitrary function to test:
func = lambda pt: (pt**2).sum()

# collect func's values at grid pts
for i in range(pts[0].shape[0]):
    for j in range(pts[1].shape[0]):
        for k in range(pts[2].shape[0]):
            vals[i,j,k] = func(np.array([pts[0][i], pts[1][j], pts[2][k]]))
```

So finally,

```
rgi = irp.RegularGridInterpolator(points=pts, values=vals)
```

runs and performs as desired.

Comment: Thanks! I found this useful.

Comment: Not silly at all. thanks for sharing. this stuff is hard to understand at first

Answer (score 14):

Your answer is nicer, and it's perfectly OK for you to accept it. I'm just adding this as an "alternate" way to script it.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as spint

RGI = spint.RegularGridInterpolator

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 3) #  or  0.5*np.arange(3.) works too

# populate the 3D array of values (re-using x because lazy)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, x, x, indexing='ij')
vals = np.sin(X) + np.cos(Y) + np.tan(Z)

# make the interpolator, (list of 1D axes, values at all points)
rgi = RGI(points=[x, x, x], values=vals)  # can also be [x]*3 or (x,)*3

tst = (0.47, 0.49, 0.53)

print rgi(tst)
print np.sin(tst[0]) + np.cos(tst[1]) + np.tan(tst[2])
```

returns:

```
1.93765972087
1.92113615659
```