# Using scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator get an error "There are 100 point arrays, but values has 2 dimensions"

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I know that there is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056577/correct-usage-of-scipy-interpolate-regulargridinterpolator) explaining how to do it, but I think I followed the steps outlined in the post and still got a dimensional error.

This is what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = x ** 2
f = RegularGridInterpolator(x,y)
```

What I did is exactly the same as what the linked post does. However, I'm still getting the same error:

> There are 100 point arrays, but values has 2 dimensions

Is that because I'm dealing with 1 dimensional data? Greatly appreciated if I can get a pointer on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be

```
RegularGridInterpolator((x,), y)
```

A grid is determined by a tuple of arrays: one for the first coordinate, one for the second, etc. Here you need a tuple of 1 list.

If this seems unnecessarily complicated, it's because it is. This method is not really meant for interpolation with one-dimensional domain, where simpler methods suffice (`interp1d`, etc).